# error Route Not Defined in admin middleware group route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have This admin routes:

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Auth',
], function () {
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login_page');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => [
        'auth:admin',
    ],
], function () {

    // for all admins
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('home', 'AdminController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@index')->name('dashboard');

    // for administrator
        // users
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'users', 'as' => 'users.',], function () {
            Route::get('all', 'UserController@index')->name('index');
            Route::get('ajax', 'UserController@ajax')->name('ajax');
            Route::get('create', 'UserController@create')->name('create');
            Route::post('post', 'UserController@store')->name('store');
            Route::get('show/{id}', 'UserController@show'); // ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
            Route::post('change_status', 'UserController@change_status')->name('change_status');
            Route::post('delete', 'UserController@delete')->name('delete');
        });
});
```

I need to action form in `create.blade` for store data:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.store') }}">
```

but in action I see this error:

> >
>   "Route [users.store] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-multiauth\resources\views\admin\pages\users\create.blade.php)"

name of router not defined in users group route.
How do can i fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Route::prefix('users')->name('users.')->group(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem. The fastest answer is to run `php artisan route:list` and see if your route exists there

If it exists and there is no problem what so ever then run 
`php artisan route:clear` and if it didn't work then I have to see the whole `web.php` file

Answer (score 0):

I found problem.I need to add admin before `.users.store` like this:

```
{{ route('admin.users.store') }}
```